# How to Check IF condition in Case statement of Stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am using CASE Statement in Stored procedure. I am using like

```
create proc USP_new
(
@searchtype varchar(30),
@stateName char(2),
    @keywords varchar(300),
    @locations varchar(100),
    @searchBy varchar(20),
    @keywordOption varchar(5),
    @jobType char(4),
    @startDate varchar(20),
    @endDate varchar(20),
    @companyID int

 ) 
 as begin
 declare @mainQuery varchar(8000)
SELECT @mainQuery = 'SELECT JobID, JobTitle, CompanyInfo, JobSummaryLong, ModifiedDate 
                 FROM Jobs 
                 WHERE IsActive = 1 '
    IF @startDate = '' BEGIN
        SELECT @mainQuery = @mainQuery + 'And ModifiedDate >= ''' + @startDate + ' 00:00:00'' '
    END
    SELECT @mainQuery = @mainQuery + 'And ModifiedDate <= ''' + @endDate + ' 23:59:59'''
SELECT
CASE  @mainQuery
WHEN 'state'    THEN 'ONE'
WHEN 'keyword' THEN 'Second'
WHEN 'company' THEN 'Third'
ELSE 'Other'

END
```

I want check more condition on this 'Keyword' like When Keyword and keyword is not null then
goto THEN condition..

I used like `WHEN 'keyword' AND (@keyword IS NULL) THEN ''` but its is giving syntax error.

IT is possible to check condition like this or any other way to check this

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really hard to tell what you are trying to accomplish with this stored proc, but I think you are definitely making thing harder than they need to be.  You could probably re-write this as a single query like so:

```
SELECT 
    KeywordResult = CASE 
        WHEN @keywords = 'state' THEN 'ONE'
        WHEN @keywords = 'keyword' THEN 'Second'
        WHEN @keywords = 'company' THEN 'Third'
        ELSE 'Other' END,
    JobID, 
    JobTitle, 
    CompanyInfo, 
    JobSummaryLong, 
    ModifiedDate 
 FROM 
    Jobs 
 WHERE 
    IsActive = 1
    AND (@StartDate <> '' AND ModifiedDate >= @StartDate)
    AND ModifiedDate <= @endDate + ' 23:59:59'''
```